# Incorrect results obtained on running a model in LibTorch that was trained and exported from PyTorch

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, onnx, libtorch

I am trying to export a trained model along with weights for inference in C++ using LibTorch. However, the output tensor results do not match.

The shape of the output tensor is the same.

```
model = FCN()
state_dict = torch.load('/content/gdrive/My Drive/model/trained_model.pth')
model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
example = torch.randn(1, 3, 768, 1024)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save('/content/gdrive/My Drive/model/mymodel.pt')
```

However some warnings are generated which I think maybe causing the incorrect results to be generated.

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:137:
>   TracerWarning: Converting a tensor to a Python index might cause the
>   trace to be incorrect. We can't record the data flow of Python values,
>   so this value will be treated as a constant in the future. This means
>   that the trace might not generalize to other inputs!
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py:435:
>   RuntimeWarning: Iterating over a tensor might cause the trace to be
>   incorrect. Passing a tensor of different shape won't change the number
>   of iterations executed (and might lead to errors or silently give
>   incorrect results).'incorrect results).', category=RuntimeWarning)

Following is the LibTorch code to generate the output tensor

```
at::Tensor predict(std::shared_ptr<torch::jit::script::Module> model, at::Tensor &image_tensor) {
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    inputs.push_back(image_tensor);

    at::Tensor result = model->forward(inputs).toTensor();

    return result;
}
```

Has anyone tried using a trained PyTorch model in LibTorch?

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same issue, and found a solution:
add

`model.eval()`

before

```
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
```

and the model gives the same result in c++ as in python